# After restarting arch linux, zookeeper deletes all nodes I have added

Tags: linux, apache-zookeeper

I am configuring my zookeeper nodes and when I restart my machine all the nodes are gone. I am using the command "create /[node_name] [data]"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the default zoo.cfg, your zookeeper data directory might be in the tmp directory, which is getting cleared on boot.  Try setting it to something else, like `/var/lib/zookeeper`.

Answer (score 1):

Also ensure you are creating your nodes as CreateMode.PERMANENT
EPHEMERAL nodes will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Did you figure this out?  If not, one more WAG:

The default zoo.cfg uses a relative path for the dataDir.  So one time if you start ZK from within the bin dir the data directory will be one place, but if you start it from the directory above (via ./bin/...) then it will be a directory higher.  I would always use an absolute path there...